# Boost C++ http post get services: How to make more than one run on same port?

Tags: c++, web-services, boost

So I am trying to create some service model for my app. I need it to be in C++, based on free libs like boost ffmpeg and so on. So I found boost services. I wonder will be capable of making 2 or more apps (each of my services is stand alone app/process) share same port and just have difrent url endings. Like `http://adress:port/service1/a=2&b=3` ,   `http://adress:port/service2/c=string`. It seemed to me that theoretically it can be accomplished by creating some process like gateway for reading all incoming traffic and calling from it my service methods. I wonder where to get such open source thing or anything that would solve my problem.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was you I'd be looking at `boost::asio` (see the http server in the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)) or for something a bit higher level, the [Pion](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library) framework (which uses asio) or maybe [cpp-netlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-netlib/).  It should normally suffice to have a single server process providing mixed functionality on one port in response to parsed URLs.